# Chai Spies in Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, chai, stub

The minimal working example at [Github](https://github.com/dderjoel/spy-test)

I am using `Mocha` and `Chai` with `Chai Spies`.

I want to test if a method (`ack`|`nack`) got called in a promise, so I basically need to use chai-as-promised with chai-spies, but

`expect(notificationListener.nack).to.be.eventually.called();`

is not allowed.

How can I avoid using `setTimeout(()=>expect(notificationListener.nack).to.be.called(), 1000)`, to mitigate this issue?

Additionally, I cannot return the Promise in my actual code, since it would mess up other stuff.

Comment: Can't you mock promises and then test?

Comment: The Web server which answers the `superagent` is already mocked with 'nock', but I cannot mock the Promise itself, because that would require to change the code. I just want to add test-code instead of changing the code under test.

Comment: Can't nock be returned as new Promise.resolve(nock())?

Comment: I updated the repo, using nock. It is still the same issue. Otherwise, I don't understand you.